# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'int?'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

inside mvc3 application i'm populating dropdownlist from database using following query.
getting error on Index.cshtml

```
public mydataEntities1 dbContext = new mydataEntities1();

        public List<SelectListItem> GetPricingSecurityID()
        {
        var pricingSecurityID = (from m in dbContext.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                                Text = m.PricingSecurityID.ToString(),
                                                Value = m.PricingSecurityID.ToString()
                                         });

        return pricingSecurityID.ToList();
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> GetCUSIP()
        {
            var cusipID = (from m in dbContext.StateStreet_DailyPosition_Second
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Text = m.CUSIP.ToString(),
                                         Value = m.CUSIP.ToString()
                                     });

            return cusipID.ToList();
        }

Home.controller
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SecurityIdentifierMapping objModel = new SecurityIdentifierMapping();
            objModel.PricingSecurityID = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID();
            objModel.CUSIP = objRepository.GetCUSIP();
            return View(objModel);
        }

public partial class SecurityIdentifierMapping
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PricingSecurityID")]
        public Nullable<int> PricingSecurityID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a CUSIPID")]
        public string CUSIP { get; set; }

        public string Calculation { get; set; }
    }
```

tried `AsEnumerable()` also what to change?

Comment: Try pressing F5 (starts debugging). I think you will learn a lot

Comment: Why is : public Nullable<int> PricingSecurityID { get; set; } a Nullable<int> when your method returns List<SelectListItem>?

Comment: @Matt these properties are auto generated by EF from database tables WHAT TO DO NOW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain without seeing the definition for `SecurityIdentiferMapping`, but I'm going to guess that `PricingSecurityID` is of type `int?`.  You are trying to set the return value of `GetPricingSecurityID()` to this property, but the return value of that method is `List<SelectItemList>`

Change your `GetPricingSecurityID()` method to return an `int?` or your property to accept a `List<SelectItemList>`.

Comment: inside GetPricingSecurityID() if i made return as int? how can i select it inside dropdown without List<SelectItemList>???

Comment: @ashuthinks That's a whole new question.  I would need to see more of your code to help.

Comment: @ashuthinks.  It looks like you're doing the same thing with `CUSIP`.  You can't set a `List<SelectItemList>` to a `string` property.

Comment: Hi change properties as return List<SelectListItem>
and inside linq queries used AsEnumerable() :) working fine

Comment: HI BUT PROBLEM IS THOSE PROPERTIES ARE AUTO GENERATED BY EF SO IT IS GIVING ERROR LIKE "The entity type SecurityIdentifierMapping is not part of the model for the current context."
SO I CANT MADE CHANGES INTO AUTO GENERATED CLASSES AND PROPERTIES :( WHAT TO DO?